# How can I use CASE statement to include students that don't exist in the particular table?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

In the last selected column, I'd need the query to return students who aren't even in that table and to just fill it in with 'No Index'.  I'm having trouble writing a case statement that will allow me to do that.  I thought that just using a full outer join on the sortest table would return nulls which would be fine but it's not doing that.  Is it because I stipulated that the test score has to be 'IR' in the WHERE clause?

```
select                              
    distinct spriden_id ID,                             
    spriden_last_name ||', '||spriden_first_name || ' '|| spriden_mi "Name" ,
    to_char(nvl(rcrapp2_pell_pgi,0), '$999,999,999') EFC,
    saradap_term_code_entry "Admit Term",
    decode(saradap_styp_code, '0', 'GED (Freshman)', '1', 'Freshman (No Transfer Credits)', '2', 
        'Freshman (With College Credit)',
        '3', 'Freshman Transfer (36-44 cr)', '4', 'Sophomore Transfer (45-89 cr)', '5', 
        'Junior Transfer (90-134 cr)', '6', 'Senior Transfer (135-999 cr)' ) "Student Type",
         nvl(decode(rcrapp1_inst_hous_cde, '1', 'With Parents', '2', 'Campus Housing', '3', 'Off 
         Campus'), 'Other') "Housing",
    sortest_test_score "Index Rating"

from
    spriden
    inner join rcrapp2
    on spriden_pidm = rcrapp2_pidm
    inner join rcrapp1
    on spriden_pidm = rcrapp1_pidm
    inner join saradap
    on spriden_pidm = saradap_pidm
    full outer join sortest
    on spriden_pidm = sortest_pidm
    --rcrapp2,
    --rcrapp1,
    --saradap,
    --sortest


where 
    spriden_change_ind is null
    --and spriden_pidm = rcrapp2_pidm
    --and spriden_pidm = saradap_pidm
   -- and spriden_pidm = rcrapp1_pidm
    --and spriden_pidm = sortest_pidm

    and rcrapp1_aidy_code = rcrapp2_aidy_code
    and rcrapp1_seq_no = rcrapp2_seq_no
    and rcrapp1_infc_code = rcrapp2_infc_code

    and rcrapp1_infc_code = 'EDE'
    and rcrapp2_pell_pgi < '30000'
    and rcrapp1_curr_rec_ind = 'Y'
    and saradap_term_code_entry >= '202001'
    and rcrapp2_aidy_code = '2021'
    and saradap_apst_code = 'D'
    and saradap_resd_code = 'R'
    and saradap_styp_code in ('0','1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6')
    and rcrapp1_inst_hous_cde in ('1', '2', '3', '4')
    and sortest_tesc_code = 'IR'

order by 2 desc;
```

Comment: In short: "yes". If you need to require conditions on the rows that come from a subordinate table, you must move those conditions from the `where` clause to the `outer join... on ...` section, so that they are applied before the "outer join" operation, not after it. Only then can you write `case` expressions checking for `null` etc.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot, making progress again.

Comment: I'm still confused though, because I can't get this to return a value, it just returns null if they don't exist on the table.

Comment: case
    when exists (select 1 from sortest where sortest_tesc_code = 'IR')then round(cast(sortest_test_score as number),2)
    when (select 1 from sortest where sortest_tesc_code = 'IR') = null then 0  end "Index Rating"